# Is there a way to create specific permissions for a tab of information?

Tags: contacts, permissions

Is there a way to add more permissions to custom tabs that we add to Civi?  I would like certain tabs of information in a contact record viewable/editable to some users but not to other users.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the tabs on contact summary page via [Contact Layout](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension.

Comment: Great.  We'll look into how we can use this extension.